# How to get the 6 characters before the last occurrence of a substring in a string?

Tags: bash, shell

Given a string that is of the form:

```
variable = "info 1 keyword info 2 keyword info 3 789 info 4 keyword extra text..."
```

Desired output = "info 4"

I would like to write a command in bash to get info 4 given a keyword, obtaining the 6 characters before the last occurrence of the keyword. I have tried using the grep and cut tools, but I haven't been able to figure this problem out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash` >= 3.0 and a regex:

```
[[ "$variable" =~ .*(.{6})\ keyword ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Output:

```
info 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to bash regex operator:

```
a=${variable%\ keyword*}
a=${a: -6}
echo "$a"
```

or, in POSIX shell

```
a=${variable%\ keyword*}
a=${a#"${a%??????}"}
echo "$a"
```

Both versions assume that the variable contains the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `grep` solution with `-P` option:

```
variable="info 1 keyword info 2 keyword info 3 789 info 4 keyword extra text..."
grep -Po '.{6}(?= keyword(?!.*keyword))' <<< "$variable"
```

Output:

```
info 4
```

The regex `(?= keyword(?!.*keyword))` is a lookahead assertion which matches the beginning of the `keyword` substring which is not followed by any more `keyword`.